# Writing data to google sheets using Google Sheets API with R

Tags: r, api, google-sheets

I try to write a data frame to google sheets using R. I've successfully added data frame example from google for developers API reference method selector but got Error 404 when tried to do so from my R script.

I've successfully got API credentials by `token <- gargle::token_fetch()` with spreadsheet and drive scopes. I've inserted some blank lines in the beginning of my table:

```
sheet_ins_range <- jsonlite::fromJSON('{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertRange": {
        "range": {
          "startRowIndex": 2,
          "endRowIndex": 2,
          "sheetId": XXXXX
        },
        "shiftDimension": "ROWS"
      }
    }
  ]
}')

sheet_ins_range$requests$insertRange$range$endRowIndex <- 10

body <- jsonlite::toJSON(sheet_ins_range)

response <- POST("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}:batchUpdate", 
            body = body, encode = "json",  config(token = token))

# response: Status: 200
```

But when I try to write some data into this region I get Error Status: 404.

```
google_BU <- jsonlite::fromJSON('{
  "data": [
    {
      "range": "Sheet1!A1:D4",
      "values": [
        ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
        ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],
        ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
        ["Engine", "$100", "1", "3/20/2016"]],
      "majorDimension": "ROWS"
    }
  ],
  "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED"
}')

body <- jsonlite::toJSON(google_BU)


response <- POST("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/values:batchUpdate", 
            body = body, encode = "json",  config(token = token))

# response: Status: 404
```

I suppose I do something wrong with HTTP request, because there is nothing wrong with this request body when I use googles "Try this method" page.

Comment: Did you check the `googlesheets4` amd `googledrive` packages? They have very helpful wrappers for doing things with Google sheets through their API.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately `googlesheets4` dos not have a function to insert blank rows to any place of the sheet. Finlale i've sort of solved the problem by adding blank rows via http request  and then using `range_write()` from `googlesheets4` to write my data frame in the beginning of the sheet, but it seems to be inconsistent.